# How can i send facebook message from web page?

Tags: facebook

I can't find a code to add a button on my web site that allows users to send a message to my fanpage profile, is it possible?

Comment: Feed dialog with `to` parameter set to your page id - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/

Comment: for message i meant the private messages (2 icon top left corner FB menu)